# Chrome - Confirm Form Resubmission - Different behaviors

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, web-applications, https

In a commercial web application that uses `POST` requests frequently, it was necessary to perform `history.go(-1)` to trigger back navigation. As may others has experienced, I am getting -

> Confirm Form Resubmission ERR_CACHE_MISS

error in Chrome. However, same works just fine in Firefox (this is no a duplicate, please read on).

It is true that using `POST` requests to render content is the reason leading to above problem (without using Post/Redirect/Get design pattern).

However, while looking for an alternative solution, it was observed that in certain web sites / apps it is possible to navigate back in Chrome (cache hit) where as in some sites it fails. I have inspected all the `HTTP headers` from successful sites and it looks like `HTTP headers` are not making any difference.

Could it possibly be the browser acting differently based on the SSL certificate used by the web application or what could be the reason for back navigation working in certain web sites?

Example working  web applications :

http://gmail.com/ - Enter some random email. Click next. Enter incorrect password multiple times and use browser back button to navigate back.

https://support.hostgator.com/ - Enter some random text in search box (do this several times). Use browser back button to navigate back.

POST request used in failing web application :

```
POST /post3.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.111
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://192.168.1.111
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://192.168.1.111/post2.jsp
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identified that in Chrome back navigation fails in above work flow, unless `SSL Certificate` used in `HTTPS` communication is a valid, trusted certificate.

If you are using a self signed certificate, add the CA certificate as a `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` and everything should work as expected.